# How to find if the function is injective, surjective or both! Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an exam in Linear Algebra in a few days and there was this one question on the practice quizzes we have in our university portals! I've been trying to figure this out for a while now but I don't know how to approach this problem can you help me?

Let, $\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}$ be the orthogonal vectors of the axes of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $\vec{v}=-\vec{j}+\vec{k}$.
Let us denote by $\times$ the vector product. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be the endomorphism defined as:  $f(U)=V\times U+2U$, for each $U\in \mathbb{R}^3$.
Which of the following is true?

- $(a)$ $f$ is surjective but not injective
- $(b)$ $f$ is injective but nor surjective
- $(c)$ $t(t^2 + t - 3)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $f$
- $(d)$ $f$ is injective

The correct one is $(d)$ but I don't know how to arrive at that point! Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Endomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ are 3x3 matrices. You can figure out this matrix by finding $f\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$ explicitly.

If you find, say $f\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2x+3y\\-x+2y-3z\\x+y+z\end{pmatrix}$, then the matrix that represents $f$ is $\begin{pmatrix}2&3&0\\-1&2&-3\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$ since $$\begin{pmatrix}2&3&0\\-1&2&-3\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=f\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$

Then you can find its characteristic polynomial and determine if it is surjective or injective.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**   You can establish $d)$ by proving that the kernel is trivial.

That will also disprove $a)$ and $b)$ since if an endomorphism of a finite dimensional vector space is injective or surjective, then it is an isomorphism.

$c)$ is false, because injectivity means that zero is not an eigenvalue.

To prove injectivity, note that $|a\times b|=|a|\cdot|b|\sin\theta$, where the $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$.  So we get that $f(u)=0\implies|v|\sin\theta=2\implies |v|\ge2$ a contradiction, unless $u=0$.